# <fcntl.h> No such file or directory

Tags: c

I am trying to run the available C code at GitHub for bloom filter (https://github.com/jvirkki/libbloom). When I try to compile I get an error: fcntl.h No such file or directory. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I also check the path to locate fcntl.h, it's already there in the system (/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl.h). So I do not know what can be the issue. I try to install essential packages too but it's not solving the problem.

Comment: Perhaps something is messed up in your GCC configuration? You can check the built-in include file search paths for example with `: | gcc -xc -E -v -` (see [What are the GCC default include directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories) for example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install git and build-essential packages

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
```

Then clone repository and compile software:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/jvirkki/libbloom.git
cd libbloom
make
```

Then check that library was compiled:

```
$ ls ./build/libbloom.so
./build/libbloom.so
```

---

If steps above does not help install the following packages manually:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev linux-libc-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: I try both steps but its not working still. It gives me same error.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the packaging system:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/include/fcntl.h
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/fcntl.h
```

or even

```
$ dpkg -S fcntl.h| wc -l
45
```

to find the 45 packages that have an `fcntl.h`

Comment: what it will give me? just to locate packages?